# Why does this query in Google Sheets, with dates, still return the first row?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, when I use the following query, with TODAY() being set to the day after tomorrow:

=QUERY(Master!A2:R1000,"select H, K where K > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)

| H | K |
| --- | --- |
| 7-14 | 9/30/2023 10:43 PM |
| 8-16 | 9/30/2023 10:34 PM |

I'm expecting it to return N/A (no results found), but instead, it returns:

7-14    9/30/2023 10:43 PM

Why is this the case? K being later than the day two days from now should be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing that final "1", and put a "0" instead. You're telling the QUERY that row A2:R2 is the header

```
=QUERY(Master!A2:R1000,"select H, K where K > date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

Comment: this fixed it!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

*Within this test formula:*

```js
=query(A1:B3,"select *",0)
```

- *the third parameter `[headers]` is usually set to `0` to tell query there's no headers in that range; setting it as `1` attributes the first row as headers (which is most likely happening in your case pulling in the first row)*
- as per [query documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343): *If omitted or set to -1, the value
  is guessed based on the content of data*

Comment: this fixed it!! thank you so much!